# htaccess impossible to remove index.php?page= tried 5 codes

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

My php code:

```
<?php $definedPages = array ( 'dir/site5', 'site1' );
                $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : 'default.php';
                if(in_array($page, $definedPages)) {
                include "{$page}.php";
                } else {
                include "default.php";
                }
            ?>
```

I want remove from my url "index.php?page="

My links now look like this:

```
example.pl/index.php?page=site1
example.pl/index.php?page=site2
example.pl/index.php?page=dir/site5
example.pl/index.php?page=dir/site6
```

I want my links to look like this:

```
example.pl/site1
example.pl/site2
example.pl/dir/site5
example.pl/dir/site6
```

All codes wchich tried and didnt work:

Code 1:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

Code 2:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(Application|Library|Bin) - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUESTFILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUESTFILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php?/page=$0 [PT,L]
```

Code 3:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC, QSA]
```

Code 4:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Other codes

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: If you claim that it is impossible, then why do you expect us to be able to help?

Comment: First thing would be to make sure the consideration of distributed configuration files is enabled at all (see the documentation for the `AllowOverride` directive on that). Second is to make sure the rewriting module is actually loaded and enabled in the apache http server. And third you should monitor your http server's error log file to see if there are any related entries in there. A debugging option would be to enable rewrite logging, again check the documentation to learn how. It allows you to understand exactly what is going on inside your rewriting engine on a step by step level.

Comment: Did you change what the links look like in your HTML to begin with?

Comment: How many urls have you got, that need rewriting ?

Answer (score 0):

The first part is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

I removed the ampersand. This appears to work for all your cases.